# Make DT editable but only accept positive numbers as input

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is it possible to have a datatable (DT R Shiny) which is editable, but the numeric columns only accept positive values?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris,
      editable = TRUE,
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = 1, className = "dt-right")
        )
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see is to use a proxy to prevent negative values. For example here, I set the edited value to 0 if the user enters a negative value. One could also open a modal dialog with the same observer to notify the user.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  dat <- iris
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat,
      editable = TRUE,
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = 1, className = "dt-right")
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("dtable")
  
  observeEvent(input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["dtable_cell_edit"]]
    if(info[["value"]] < 0) {
      info[["value"]] <- 0
      # here one could open a modal or a notification
    }
    dat <<- editData(dat, info, proxy = proxy)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```